# Tables not getting fetched when deploying web2py app on GAE

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, web2py

WHen I am trying to deploy a web2py app on google app engine, the tables which I defined using db.define.table are not getting imported as I am not able to retrieve any row from any of such tables.

In db.py I have used google datastore though.

```
if not request.env.web2py_runtime_gae:
    ## if NOT running on Google App Engine use SQLite or other DB
    db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite',pool_size=1,check_reserved=['all'])
else:
db = DAL('google:datastore')
from gluon.contrib.memdb import MEMDB
from google.appengine.api.memcache import Client
session.connect(request, response, db = MEMDB(Client()))
```

Only these changes I have made. On hosting it to GAE, the html page doesn't show those contents which are to be taken from table. Rest of the contents it is showing.
First time I am deploying something on GAE . I have just added an app.yaml and queue.yaml in web2py folder and have edited app.yaml accordingly.

HELP !!

Comment: Are you saying you were running the app locally (and therefore using SQLite) and have now deployed to GAE, but you no longer see the data that you entered locally? If so, that is as expected, as you haven't done anything to copy the data from SQLite to GAE.

Comment: @Anthony now I got it. Actually I made entities in cloud datastore and copied data entries there and I am able to access those data now in GAE. But I am not able to upload images in those entities as only string,boolean,key,datetime,number and keys are allowed.

Comment: Thats  completely unrelated to this question. Read the s.o. faq and make a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You have only stored data locally. Its a dev environment. After you deploy you need to also create your data on the production storage services like sql, datastore, blobstore etc.
later whn you deploy new versions the data will still be there. All versions share the same storage.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not able to upload images in the cloud datastore entities

Comment: Thats completely unrelated to the original question or this answer.

Comment: Yeah My mistake. Now I have asked a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543055/store-images-in-datastore-of-gae-python-while-deploying-web2py-app           . Please help